# Moving Average across Variables in Stata

Tags: foreach, stata, moving-average

I have a panel data set for which I would like to calculate moving averages across years.

Each year is a variable for which there is an observation for each state, and I would like to create a new variable for the average of every three year period. 
For example:

```
P1947=rmean(v1943 v1944 v1945), P1947=rmean(v1944 v1945 v1946)
```

I figured I should use a `foreach` loop with the `egen` command, but I'm not sure about how I should refer to the different variables within the loop.

I'd appreciate any guidance!

Comment: It's Stata. This has already been pointed out to you.

Comment: Note that `rmean()` works for `egen` but has not been documented as from Stata 9 onwards. The documented `egen` function name is `rowmean()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This data structure is quite unfit for purpose. Assuming an identifier `id` you need to `reshape`, e.g.

```
 reshape long v, i(id) j(year) 
 tsset id year
```

Then a moving average is easy. Use `tssmooth` or just `generate`, e.g.

```
 gen mave = (L.v + v + F.v)/3
```

or (better)

```
 gen mave = 0.25 * L.v + 0.5 * v + 0.25 * F.v
```

More on why your data structure is quite unfit: Not only would calculation of a moving average need a loop (not necessarily involving `egen`), but you would be creating several new extra variables. Using those in any subsequent analysis would be somewhere between awkward and impossible.

EDIT I'll give a sample loop, while not moving from my stance that it is poor technique. I don't see a reason behind your naming convention whereby `P1947` is a mean for 1943-1945; I assume that's just a typo. Let's suppose that we have data for 1913-2012. For means of 3 years, we lose one year at each end.

```
forval j = 1914/2011 { 
    local i = `j' - 1 
    local k = `j' + 1       
    gen P`j' = (v`i' + v`j' + v`k') / 3 
}
```

That could be written more concisely, at the expense of a flurry of macros within macros. Using unequal weights is easy, as above. The only reason to use `egen` is that it doesn't give up if there are missings, which the above will do.

FURTHER EDIT

As a matter of completeness, note that it is easy to handle missings without resorting to `egen`.

The numerator

```
    (v`i' + v`j' + v`k')
```

generalises to

```
    (cond(missing(v`i'), 0, v`i') + cond(missing(v`j'), 0, v`j') + cond(missing(v`k'), 0, v`k')
```

and the denominator

```
    3
```

generalises to

```
    !missing(v`i') + !missing(v`j') + !missing(v`k')
```

If all values are missing, this reduces to 0/0, or missing. Otherwise, if any value is missing, we add 0 to the numerator and 0 to the denominator, which is the same as ignoring it. Naturally the code is tolerable as above for averages of 3 years, but either for that case or for averaging over more years, we would replace the lines above by a loop, which is what `egen` does.

Answer (score 0):

There is a user written program that can do that very easily for you. It is called `mvsumm` and can be found through `findit mvsumm`

```
xtset id time 
mvsumm observations, stat(mean) win(t) gen(new_variable) end
```

Comment: `mvsumm` assumes a single response variable, so that it is only applicable to panel data held as a long structure. The main point of the question here is that the OP has a wide data structure. This answer is correct for the OP's data only after reshaping, as explained in detail in my answer.

Comment: I oversaw that the panel data is wide. Nick is of course correct in his answer.